# How to add my jars in local repository using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Is there any option for adding jars in local repository using eclipse and without using cmd prompt.

Comment: your question is not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes there is a [Maven M2E](https://eclipse.org/m2e/) plugin for eclipse. Which enables you to perform all the maven operations from within the eclipse.

Open Eclipse IDE

Click Help -> Eclipse Marketplace...

Search for M2E & install